# JsonResult with numbers as field names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jsonresult

I need to return a JSON result from my ASP.NET MVC 3 application like this:

```
{ 0: value1, 1: value2 }
```

But I can't create an object with anonymous type that would have numbers as field names.
So what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict["0"] = "value1";
dict["1"] = "value2";

var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var output = serializer.Serialize(dict);
```

The output is

```
 {"0":"value1","1":"value2"}
```